# Storyboard can't be executed twice

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I tried to use an animation in my app and I'm using only two pages to test the animation.

When the app starts for the first time, I want to animate my application title with a sliding effect.  The title should come from outside the page.

I used the following code:

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"
                   Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ApplicationTitleTransIn" TranslateX="-200"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:0.5">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.7"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ApplicationTitleTransIn" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" 
                        From="-200" To="0">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

And it works pretty well.

When I click a button, my application title should move to the right side of my page and then the second page should be displayed.

I created the following storyboard:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="ApplicationTitleTransOut">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ApplicationTitle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="600">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

In the code behind, the storyboard is executed as follow:

```
 ApplicationTitleTransOut.Completed += delegate
            {
                ApplicationTitleTransOut.Stop();

                var vm = DataContext as MainViewModel;

                if (vm != null)
                {
                    vm.OpenPageCommand.Execute(listBox.SelectedItem as TileItem);
                }
            };

        ApplicationTitleTransOut.Begin();
```

The text will move to the right side of my page and then I'll navigate to the second page.

Until now everything works.

But when I press the back button (on the phone) I've an exception.

```
ExceptionObject = {System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetName ApplicationTitleTransIn.}
```

Did I miss something? Is this the right way to achieve this animation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I would structure the XAML layout differently. First of all, it does not seem that you need `CompositeTransform`, but just `TranslateTransform`. In this case, use this snippet for `RenderTransform`:

```
<TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ApplicationTitleTransIn" X="-200"/>
</TextBlock.RenderTransform>
```

Now, when you are binding the `DoubleAnimation` to it, use relative property conventions:

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.7"
Storyboard.TargetName="ApplicationTitle"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
From="-200" To="0">
```

Same applies to your `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"  Storyboard.TargetName="ApplicationTitle">
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: I applied your solution and it works like a charm :) And now when I press the back button the application title position is set at -200 correctly before to display my page.  With my solution the position was 0 then -200 and animated to 0 (it was a weird behavior).